# Can i use Kali Linux and windows simultaneously without partitions of drives

Tags: linux, windows, kali-linux

I am having a doubt about installing Kali Linux. Can I install Kali Linux on USB. I am currently having windows 7 32 bit. The real doubt is can I run Kali Linux and windows simultaneously after one another with USB without dual boot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes what you are looking for is possible and there plenty of documentation for it. 
Just run over to the official documentation.

http://docs.kali.org/category/downloading

And check out both articles.

I down voted you as a very simple search would have brought up the documentation.

Comment: And what about Kali Linux live

Comment: What are you even talking about??? 
Look at the dang instructions.